# How to make a histogram showing the distribution of a set of variables, grouped by another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

Here's the idea: I have a dataframe with several x columns, let's call them x1, x2, x3. I also have a binary column y. For each x column, I wish to create a histogram* showing the distribution of that column by y. For example, for x1, I want one histogram showing the distribution for the subgroup of x1 that has y=1 and another histogram - on the same chart - showing the distribution for the subgroup of x1 that has y=0.

To clarify, I want the two histograms for each column on the same chart, but I want each column to have its own chart. Please let me know if that does make sense.

I am working with pandas.

I have been researching this a bit now and have not yet been able to get the precise solution I need. Thank you in advance for your help.

*If you know of a different type of chart better suited to this purpose, please let me know.

Comment: Why not 2 pie charts for each x column, one for y=1 and one for y=0, then just line the 6 pie charts into a table of 2 by 3?

Comment: Because I want to see if there's a difference in the distributions for the subgroups. That is, I'm not interested in the percent of each column that satisfies y=1, I'm interested in seeing if there is a difference between the distribution of datapoints in column xi that satisfy y=1 and the distribution of datapoints in column xi that satisfy y=0. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see - well, matplotlib subplots should do the trick? Slice up your dataframe into subgroups and use them to plot histograms in a grid: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

Comment: Would that allow me to have the different subgroup plots on the same graph and keep the different columns' plots on different graphs?

Comment: Yes, it's all about how you slice your data. It's very flexible.